# Spring Boot running on Docker - Liquibase Issue (liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException:)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, liquibase

I have a problem to run **Spring Boot App** on **Docker**. It covers also liquibase for data migration.

When I run this command (`docker-compose up -d`), I got this issue shown below.

```
2023-06-19 17:19:10 Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
2023-06-19 17:19:10      2 changesets check sum
2023-06-19 17:19:10           db/changelog/changes/1-ays-ddl.xml::1-ays-ddl::author was: 8:9eff502dc64e86c139e2705d0a5ad7f5 but is now: 8:6b1f7f790c04285a35dc3acd3e89a0f4
2023-06-19 17:19:10           db/changelog/changes/2-ays-dml.xml::2-ays-ddl::author was: 8:dc54e5ca8ce5cf11784d3d29ef0cd3c0 but is now: 8:f34f4332cdb9f4dd708875364cd476a0
2023-06-19 17:19:10
```

Here are the changeSets shown below

```
<changeSet id="1-ays-ddl" author="author">
<changeSet id="2-ays-dml" author="author">
```

Even id I deleted all **images** related with it, I still get the same error message.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase prevvent the application from starting because the checksum of 2 changesets have change.
this will happen whenever you modify any changeset already applied to the database.
=> rollback any change done on these changesets then create new one

Comment: How can I rollback and create new one?

Comment: Do your project is versioned using GIT ?
If so, you can revert the commit in which you modified the changesets

Comment: My problem is in Docker. I can run it locally without any issue.

Comment: Locally you I assume that you're using h2 database.
If so, your app start with an clear database on which liquibase apply all your change set.
When running your docker this is not the case, I mean the database used by your docker is not empty when the app start.
And on this database older versions of the changesets have already been applied, which prevent the application from starting